# How can I delete text appended to droppable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a clear button to appear whenever an element is dropped into a droppable div. Problem is that the button was also created to clear the html within the div and upon clear the item I wanted the button the fade away.

```
$('#sortcard, #dropbox, #dropbox1').droppable({accept:'.sorting', hoverClass:'border', tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function (e, ui){

    $(e.target).append(ui.draggable.html() + '<br/>');
        //can use $(this) or (e.target)
    $("#add_friend").show().fadeOut(12000);
    $(e.target).droppable("destroy");
    $(e.target).append("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>");
    }
    });

    $(":button").click(function(){
        $(ui.draggable).remove;
        $(":button").fadeOut(20000)        
    });
```

Yet, as seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/136/) it's just not happening. I would love to understand why my button is not working like I want and how to fix this problem. Any other tips in general would also greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Edited to remove use of "live" (deprecated).

Your click handler is trying to bind to an element that does not exist yet. Try binding the click handler at the time the button is created:

Old:

```
$(e.target).append("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>");}
```

New:

```
$(e.target).append($("<input type='button' name='Sub' value='clear'/>")
           .click(function(){
               $(this).parent().empty();
               $(this).fadeOut(20000);
            }));
```

Comment: The `live()` method is deprecated. Use `on()` instead ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). Also, `$(":button").fadeOut(20000)` will hide all buttons on the page. Use `$(this)` instead.

Comment: @pmandell tried your method as seen http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/152/ and still no removal of droppable text after button is pressed

Comment: @jfrej My buttons were not hidden, as a matter of fact nothing happened as seen http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/152/

Comment: @Octavius You made a typo in `$("this").fadeOut(20000);` - remove the double quotes. It should be `$(this)`

Comment: @jfrej How can I make it so the words are only deleted and not the whole div? .children?

Comment: **$(this).empty();** I am still unclear on what exactly your desired end result is, so hope this works!

Comment: The desired result is to have a button that erases the elements dropped in the droppable. At the same time I want the button to fade away after it is clicked

Comment: You should use a class for all of the drop locations. How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/AXPhG/1/

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(":button").fadeOut(20000)
```

to

```
$(this).fadeOut(20000)
```